# Issue with PrintWriter?

Tags: java, printing, printwriter

I have a method (PrintTree) which returns a string (treeString), with multiple lines. The string looks like this:

```
html 
head
link
body
```

When I print it to the console, it prints the String correctly. However, when I try to use the printWriter, it doesn't output anything.

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(filePath);
out.write(PrintTree(root));
out.close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using obsolete classes to start with? Use `Files.newBufferedWriter()`.

Comment: Did you get some exception ?

Comment: No exception. When I take out the \n in my method that constructs my String (putting everything on one line), it prints out. However, I'm trying to get everything to print out on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter` is buffered. As such, it will only "commit" writes when its internal buffer is full (and that is implementation specific) or when you `.flush()` it.

Anyway, this is 2016. So, don't use that. Use `Files.newBufferedWriter()`, and a try-with-resources statement:

```
final Path outfile = Paths.get(...);

try (
    final Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
) {
    out.write(PrintTree(root));
}
```

It is all the more important to act this way to detect errors early that, [quoting the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions**, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking checkError().

And it is too easy, way too easy, to not call `.checkError()`.